# Can't start with profiles in spring + maven + tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I need to use profiles with spring. I use local Tomcat.
There is maven project, so, in pom.xml I added:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                    <value>dev</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>8.0.11</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>at1</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                    <value>at1</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

and in application.properties added spring.profiles.active=${activatedProperties}
note: spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@ tried already too

and there is two files application-at1.properties and application-dev.properties

When build war with -Dspring.profiles.active=dev there is error message - params from this files not found.

My tomcat customizations are:

[image]

Comment: Don't... Spring Profiles aren't Maven Profiles (and vice versa) this approach will lead you to building different deployable artifacts for different environments. Which basically lead to propagating untested code to the next environment. Just include everything in your archive and only use Spring Profiles.

Comment: Added a couple of answers because I'm not sure where you left off. I'm thinking that the last point is what you actually need.

Answer (score 2):

Can't tell exactly where you are but seems to me that you're using a property place holder, Spring Boot is not picking up a profile because the placeholder actually has no value.

You can configure this in the following way:

**Using Property Placeholders:**

application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=${activatedProperties}
```

pom.xml

```
<property>
   <name>activatedProperties</name>
   <value>dev</value>
</property>
```

**Just specify the runtime argument**

Remove property from pom.xml and adjust your application.properties with some default value or don't specify it at all

```
spring.profiles.active=at1 #you can remove this line if you want.
```

Then run-war with argument `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

**Working with Maven Profiles**

You can run maven with a `-P dev` to make sure that the goal is executed with the correct profile.

Comment: the runtime argument: I replaced  package -D="ru.sbrf.risks.services.data.UnitTest"-Dspring.profiles.active=dev to just package and added -Dspring.profiles.active=dev to jvm params to start - the error is same.

Comment: is it okey, thats after mvn clean package... --P dev in result war-file located three property-files(application.property, application-dev.property and application-qa.properties) ?